# Inequality in a proof about total variation, $T_a^b (f) \leq \text{lim inf} \ T_a^b (f) $

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{f_n\} $ be a sequence of functions in $[a,b]$ that converge pointwise in $[a,b]$ to a function $f.$ Then, $T_a^b (f) \leq \text{lim inf} \ T_a^b (f) $

I don't understand some things about the proof.

First, I pick a partition in $[a,b]$ and an $\epsilon > 0 .$ And consider $$ \sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})|\leq  \sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_k) - f_n(x_{k-1})| +\sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_{k-1}) - f_n(x_{k-1})| \\+\sum_{k=1}^K |f_n(x_k) - f_n(x_{k-1})| .$$ 
I really don't understand why is this inequality happening.

I don't see why $ \sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_k) - f_n(x_{k})|$ can be replaced by 
$ \sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_k) - f_n(x_{k-1})|$ in order to say that

$ \sum_{k=1}^K |f(x_k) - f_n(x_{k-1})| \leq K\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| &= |f(x_k)-f_n(x_{k-1})+f_n(x_{k-1})-f_n(x_{k})+f_n(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| \\
&\le |f(x_k)-f_n(x_{k-1})|+|f_n(x_{k-1})-f_n(x_{k})|+|f_n(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|.
\end{align*}